# How do I scale matplotlib figure output to A3?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a networkx node graph being output/saved to PDF/PNG/SVG whatever I choose, but the problem is when I run the code the graph is very square and central and doesn't fit to the canvas sides well.

The result is an A3 print out that is small and has a lot of space-waste around the graph.

Here's the code:

```
plt_k.figure(figsize=(30,30))
plt_k.axis('off')
...
plt_k.savefig('./pdf_output/test.pdf', orientation='landscape', papertype='a3', format='pdf', dpi=400)
```

I'm doing a `spring_layout` type graph which changes shape each time I execute the code. I've found that if I use a `figsize` of less dimension than `(30,30)` the plot output is cropped.

How can I improve the plot output such that the graph fills the page?

Comment: The graph is square because you told it to make a 30x30" graph.  If you want A3 in landscape, then try `figsize=(16.53, 11.69)`.  As for any cropping, that's hard to understand w/o an example of what you are trying to plot.  By default, Matplotlib only crops things that are outside the axes.

Comment: @JodyKlymak  -OK. If `figsize=(16.53, 11.69)` is the canvas, but matplotlib crops the plot outside the axes this suggests there are other instructions to force the plot inside the canvas dimension, or at least to make the axes scale the same as the canvas, correct?

Comment: The axes is by default positioned between 0.1 and 0.95 the figure width and 0.1 and 0.9 the figure height if I recall correctly.  You can change this with ax.set_position.